# Cookie settings detection not working on IE 11

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I use the following approach to check if Cookies are enabled. It works fine on FireFox and Google Chrome but it fails on IE 11.

The approach consist of creating a cookie in one page then redirecting to another page that reads the cookie. If the cookie can be red then we assume cookies are enabled.

In IE 11, I went and set the privacy slider of both internet and intranet zone to its top most value (Block All Cookies) but cookies always seemed enabled regardless.

Here is the code (pulled from msdn):

**Default Page:**

> ```
> Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>     If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
>         If Request.QueryString("AcceptsCookies") Is Nothing Then
>             Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Value = "ok"
>             Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
>             Response.Redirect("CheckCookies.aspx?redirect=" & Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString))
>         Else
>             lblCookie.Text = "Accept cookies = " & Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("AcceptsCookies"))
>         End If
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

**Cookie Checking Page:**

> ```
> Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>     Dim redirect As String = Request.QueryString("redirect")
>     Dim acceptsCookies As String
>     If Request.Cookies("TestCookie") Is Nothing Then
>         acceptsCookies = "no"
>     Else
>         acceptsCookies = "yes"
>         Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
>     End If
>     Response.Redirect(redirect & "?AcceptsCookies=" & acceptsCookies, True)
> End Sub
> ```

Can anyone figure out why this approach is not working on IE 11?

Does anyone have a 100% reliable method to check if cookies are disabled?

Is it possible that the IE-11 cookie blocker simply does not work?

Thanks!