# AntiFogeryToken Cookie is always store and send back to server even when i block all cookies on IE 11 (other browsers work as expected)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, internet-explorer-11

Im currently set up a feature which allow server side code aware of whether this browser is enable cookie or not.

the solution is to use antiforgery cookie which is sent back to server whenever client post a request. Then i check that the request contains antiforgery cookie or not.
This solution work fine on Chrome. But on IE11, when i block all cookies  , it can not work. My approach is quite similar with this ([Cookie settings detection not working on IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685921/cookie-settings-detection-not-working-on-ie-11))

1. I don't know why IE 11 still write down antiforgery cookie while all cookies settings are blocked?
2. And this cookie is also send back to server code whenever client posts a request

Comment: Try to check the html elements, if you are using "@Html.AntiForgeryToken()", it will generate a input hidden filed to store the token, please check your code whether it rebuild the request url and recreate the cookie.

Comment: Thanks @ZhiLv-MSFT finally i figured out that cookies settings of IE11 is not impact on localhost domain, it will work when we have domain like (abc.net,...)